# Quickbooks magento integration with soap

Tags: magento, integration, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am working in **magento**. Just I want to extend my **magento** with `quickbooks` services with soap. Can you please me the process to call soap service from **magento** with `quickbooks`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use solutions already designed for quickbooks integration. See http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/quickbooks-integration-pro-premier-enterprise.html. Or you can use the [Quickbooks SDK/Web connector](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0010_get_oriented/0080_quickbooks_web_connector) to build a custom solution of your own.